# Gradle on Jenkins

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins

I have a project which consist of several modules declared in the settings.gradle file:

```
include ':core_icons'
include ':core'
```

`core_icons` is used by the core module as an versioned dependency:

```
compile 'com.company.core:icons:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

On Jenkins, the build does not run because Gradle is looking for the dependency
in the local maven cache but can't find it:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':core'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':core:_debugPublishCopy'.
   > Could not find com.company.core:icons:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.
```

It seems like Gradle tries to find already each dependency then it starts up.

I tried to reproduce this on my local machine by clearing the dependencies from my local maven cache but then I am able to build the project without any problems via:

```
gradlew core_icons:install
```

I checked the Gradle versions, both are equal (2.14.1)

I tried to invoke on Jenkins the build exactly the same, but it does not work because it can't find the dependency.

When removing the the core module from the settings.gradle the build runs fine on Jenkins.

Anybody knows why this is happening only on Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem, here it is:

The problem was that I had a dependency to core_icons which just gets created during that build like this:

```
compile 'com.company.core:icons:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Since this represents a dependency which should be found in the local Maven repo or in MavenCentral, Gradle was not able to find it.

Just reference the dependency like a normal Project, like so:

```
compile project(':core_icons')
```

Then you can invoke also the install goal later to publish your artifacts to the Maven repo as a snapshot or release version.